# Add/Remove Items to Android ListView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I am creating a listview as `ListView listView = new ListView(context);` in my activity and I code MyCustomAdapter that extends BaseAdaptor.setting this custom adapter to my `listView.setAdapter(myCustomAdpObj)` object that I created as above.Now at run time I want to add/remove elements from this listView.I did't find the method how I can do this?any suggestion?thanks

Comment: from your item array just remove or add item and call your adapter's notifyDataSetChanged().

Comment: You have to change the underlying data that you are passing to listview adapter, use notifyDataSetChanged() API.

Comment: what exactly myCustomAdpObj is?

Comment: @Paresh Mayani myCustomAdpObj is object name for my custom Adapter.I am going to try suggested method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove/add an element and use this.

```
((BaseAdapter) listView.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetInvalidated();
```

Answer (score 2):

from your item array just remove or add item and call your adapter's `notifyDataSetChanged()`