# change Android ListView component

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

[image]I am very thankful for this very nice site.
Here I am extending my [Add/Remove Items to Android ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7712321/add-remove-items-to-android-listview) post with one more situation.
I am creating a listview as ListView listView = new ListView(context); in my activity and I code MyCustomAdapter that extends BaseAdaptor.setting this custom adapter to my listView.setAdapter(myCustomAdpObj) object that I created as above.In getView(..) method of MyCustomAdapter class I am using my custom Layout class as MyCustomView extends LinearLayout and MyCustomView contain GUI components like TextView ImageView etc.It means I have three different classes as MyActivity,MyCustomAdapter and MyCustomView.Now in MyActivity I want to access specific element like ImageView and want to change its background or src image.any help?

Comment: Does this correctly summarize your question: "How can I change individual views in each list item in my ListView based on the data bound to each list item?"

Comment: @Dan S first yes I am dynamically adding views to my ListView.now I want to change the some items(like ImageView background or TextView text etc) at run time of already added items?

Comment: Is your getView() dynamically adding and removing views or just creating your list items? This all relates to how complicated your binder will be.

Comment: @Dan S yes its daynamically adding and creating views also.below I am pasting MyCustomAdapter's getView complete method private List<UserBean> currentUserBean;
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  UserBean userBean = currentUserBean.get(position);  
  View v = new MyCustomView(this.context, userBean);  
  return v;
 }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Dan S thanks for your answer but with handler its working fine.There is need to put the hanlder to update GUI when we are calling Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();.It mean if notifyDataSetChanged ListView not updating then put handler post method inside this method call this notifyDataSetChanged

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to move to a SimpleAdapter or SimpleCursorAdapter (depending on your backend data). From there use the `ViewBinder` so that you can customize the look and feel of your list items based on the data. This is also where you will bind data manually with `ViewBinder.setViewValue` this method will be called before any automatic binding happens so you can return false to allow automatic binding to occur. (Automatic binding only works with ImageView and TextView.)

Comment: it means its not possible to change ImageView image when I use my custom Adapter that is extending BaseAdapter ?

Comment: It is possible to use `getView` to change the content but it is more cumbersome to do it that way.

Comment: now I am able to add new view to existing ListView using this code MyChatListBean newChatBean = chatSessionArrayList.get(index);newChatBean.setMsgStatus(statustype);   chatSessionArrayList.set(index, newChatBean); ((BaseAdapter)listView.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged(); I also attach an image with my main post.now problem is coming notifyDataSetChanged() does not show the newly added image,but when I hide and show the soft-keyboard by clicking on EditText of my chat screen as shown in above picture view displayed.Its looking ListView not refreshing or else?how to refresh a ListView?

Comment: If `SimpleAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` isn't working try `SimpleAdapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated()`.